# The constant Build.TIME in Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk

What exactly the constant "long android.os.Build.TIME" means?

I tested in my device and I get a strange number which I do not know the meaning.

In http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html, it is not explained.

Comment: My guess is that it is the time when the firmware was built, probably as milliseconds since the Unix epoch (i.e., the time base used by `System.currentTimeMillis()`), but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @CommonsWare correctly commented: it's a Unix epoch timestamp (in milliseconds) of when the device's ROM was built.

If you dig into the source of the `Build` class, you'll find the following:

```
// The following properties only make sense for internal engineering builds.
public static final long TIME = getLong("ro.build.date.utc") * 1000;
```

In other words: the value is simply read from the `ro.build.date.utc` system property, which is part of the ROM's `build.prop`, which on its turn gets generated by [`buildinfo.sh`](https://github.com/android/platform_build/blob/master/tools/buildinfo.sh).

The more human-friendly equivalent is `ro.build.date`, which contains a textual date representation of the same value. For example, in `build.prop` you may find:

```
ro.build.date=Tue Nov 6 13:10:27 CST 2012
ro.build.date.utc=1352229027
```

There is no associated constant for it in Android's public API, but you could easily retrieve it by calling `SystemProperties.get("ro.build.date")`.

That being said, unless you develop for specific ROMs and/or are a ROM developer, you shouldn't really have to care about these values, as the comment in the first code snippet also points out.

Comment: I understood. Tank you very much.